# Как решить эту задачу через динамические массивы?

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++

Даны натуральное число n (n≥2) и действительный квадратный массив размера nxn. Построить последовательность b1, b2, ..., bn  из нулей  и единиц, в которой  bi = 1 тогда и только тогда, когда элементы i-й строки матрицы образуют возрастающую последовательность.

---

Код работает как надо, но нужно через динамические массивы, а не обычные

```
int main() 
{
int n;
int flag;
double arr[100][100];
double b[100];
cout << "Enter array size: ";
cin >> n;
cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cout << "Enter " << "[" << i + 1 << "][" << j + 1 << "] element of massive >> ";
        cin >> arr[i][j];
    }
}

cout << endl << "Your array:" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cout << setw(4) << arr[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
    flag = 1;
    for (int j = 0;j < n - 1 && flag == 1;j++)
        if (arr[i][j + 1] <= arr[i][j]) flag = 0;
    b[i] = flag;
}

cout << endl << "The answer is: ";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << b[i] << ' ';
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Узнав значение n, выделяйте память, типа, `double * b = new double[int];` Как выделять память для двумерного массива - поищите, здесь этот вопрос уже много раз поднимался...

Comment: а зачем здесь вообще массивы?..

Comment: @pavel по требованию препода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    int flag;
    double** arr;
    double* b;
    cout << "Enter array size: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    arr = new double*[n];
    b = new double[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = new double[n];

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << "Enter " << "[" << i + 1 << "][" << j + 1 <<
                 "] element of massive >> ";
            cin >> arr[i][j];
            }
        }

    cout << endl << "Your array:" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << setw(4) << arr[i][j];
            }

        cout << endl << endl;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        flag = 1;

        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1 && flag == 1; j++)
            if (arr[i][j + 1] <= arr[i][j]) flag = 0;

        b[i] = flag;
        }

    cout << endl << "The answer is: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << b[i] << ' ';
        }

    delete[] b;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        delete[] arr[i];
        }

    delete[]arr;
    return 0;
    }
```